# Grails web deploy in Tomcat got HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Tags: grails, groovy

Grails war deploy in Tomcat gives me this error:

[image: 1]

Can you please help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: Yes sir, Pls help me

Comment: Please read through all the guides above and edit your question

Comment: How did you get to that URL? Do other pages load okay? Do you have a controller named AlipayOnlinePaymentController? Is the controller using scaffolding or does it have an index method? If you have an index method do you have a gsp file like /views/alipayOnlinePayment/index.gsp ? Judging by the URL I'd guess you have something named incorrectly as the first letter of Alipay... should be lowercase

Comment: Oh @MikeW I have one more URL http://localhost:8100/singleTradeQuery and  in my enviroment work fine. After I build grails war and deploy to the Tomcat not work anymore.

Comment: I used grails web profile. I just want the data response only.

Comment: Check your tomcat logs and repost

Comment: Are you sure that Tomcat is using 8080 port or is it using 8100 port or port 80?

Comment: Thank you all for helping me, I found out